# For a Gradle Java project, how to access a file from resource folder which is placed in the distribution zip or war file of the project?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a java code snippet where I am trying to access one of the files from the resources folder. 
Project structure:

```
|--src/main/java
|----core
|----resources
```

Java code to get the path for this file:

```
String defaultDictionaryPath = getClass().getResource("/resources/textFile.txt").toURI().getPath();
```

This is the gradle build file code I have written to include the resources in the distribution zip folder.

```
mainClassName = 'core.MainClassName'

applicationDistribution.from("src/main/java/resources") {
    into "resources"
}
```

The successful build generates a build folder:

```
|--build
|----classes
|----distributions
|------ProjectName.tar
|--------bin
|----------ProjectName.bat
|--------lib
|--------resources
|------ProjectName.zip
|--------bin
|----------ProjectName.bat
|--------lib
|--------resources
|----libs
|----reports
|----scripts
|----test-results
|----tmp
```

After the build when I have to run the project I unzip the `ProjectName.zip` folder under `distributions` and run the `ProjectName.bat` file. That's when it is not able to find the file under `resources` and I get NullPOinterException error.

1. Am I specifying the resource folder path correctly?
2. Or am I not running the project correctly?
3. Or am i missing on something in gradle build file.

I am a newbie in Gradle so please pardon if I am asking silly questions.
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.